# Real Time Application Using Socket IO in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, socket.io, real-time

I am implementing Real time application , not a chat application.
I need help how to connect to server and fetch data from server. My application i have three events 1) init with arguments(userID) 2) FilterData with Arguments(userID)  3) FilterData with arguments (UserId) 
4) Custom offline Method for disconnect from server

1,2,4 are emit
3 is on connect method

it show error server side already connected user so disconnect first

Comment: I can't understand your problem very well. Can you provide some code exemple and a message of the error occurred in server side ?

Comment: How we implement real time app , my server side I am using Socket io